# From XP to Win 7: Unable to cast COM object to interface type. Failed due to "No such interface supported"

Tags: com

*Note: I am very, very new to Windows development*

I just converted a Visual Studio .Net 2003 solution to VS 2005 (our first step toward VS2012).  The converted VS 2005 solution works perfectly in its original 32-bit XP environment however fails with this "No such interface supported" error in 64-bit Windows 7.

```
Error 13: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Reflection.Session' to interface type 
'Reflection.DApplication'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call
on the COM component for the interface with IID '...' failed due to the following 
error: No such interface support (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))
```

Both XP and Win7 are using the same code, same 3rd party DLL and same framework (Based on the CorsFlag results below, it seems that both XP and Win7 are using the .Net 1.1 framework).  What else could be triggering this error in Win7 and not XP?

If it helps, the "Reflection.Session" and "Reflection.DApplication" are part of the IBM Reflection 9 terminal emulation software.  The terminal emulator runs fine on its own in Win7 however the API we use in this code is giving the error above when used in the Win7 environment.

---

Looking through other StackOverflow answers, I've tried the following:

1. https://superuser.com/a/480224/148513

Looking at the CorsFlags results for both the executable and the Interop.Reflection.DLL, I get this same response:

```
Version    : v1.1.4322
CLR Header : 2.0
PE         : PE32
CorFlags   : 0x1
ILONLY     : 1
32BITREQ   : 0
32BITPREF  : 0
Signed     : 0
```

I could be wrong, but am thinking that this indicates it isn't a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue.  I'm not 100% sure that 32 vs 64-bit could trigger this error anyways.

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9197769/456645

Installed "Remote Server Administration Tools" and enabled "Remote Desktop Services Tool".  After rebooting and testing again, still had no luck.

Comment: It is a pretty straight-forward problem, either IBM has changed its product, unsurprising after 10 years, or its installer did not register the proxy properly.  If SysInternals' Process Monitor doesn't help (compare good and bad) then contact IBM for support.

Comment: They have released newer versions however this is the same version of IBM Reflection on both XP and Win7.  I'll try to re-install to attempt to fix the proxy registration, and research the SysInternals idea you mentioned.  Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: Ideally, I don't want to upgrade to their newer products as we don't need the features and the API has changed significantly.